# Remove all spaces from string (including \quad and \hspace)

Tags: spacing, strings

I want to retrieve all characters besides any space (tabulation) ones including  , `~`, `\space`, `\enspace`, `\quad`, `\qquad` etc. that have been passed as an argument.

Say we have a command `\removespaces{...}` that will print

```
Loremipsumdolorsitamet
```

if I used the following sequence in the document

```latex
\removespaces{Lorem ipsum~dolor\hskip2ex sit\quad amet}
```

What is the easiest way of achieving that?

Comment: Does `\def\myquad{\quad}` then `\myquad` count? Or only those in that fixed list?

Comment: @user202729 good question, now the question seems even more harder. But basically I'm looking for a versatile way of removing spaces so that anything like `\def\quad{}` won't satisfy me.

Comment: I don't understand, why `\def\quad{}` doesn't satisfy you? Because it "executes" the content so the content inside might "look" at the definition?

Comment: I can see a few ways • do similar to what `unravel` package does, simulate TeX inside TeX and modify the behavior of spacing commands • use the analysis-map functions to analyze the input token-by-token (only works top-level) • do something with the node list and remove all the glues (might require Lua, not sure)

Comment: @user202729 I don't really want to do so manually for each of possible spacing command at least for that reason that I might miss one.

Comment: @user202729 and how would you handle `\hskip`? This primitive has some additional `plus` and `minus` optional arguments.

Comment: @user202729 everything sounds like a bulk solution with iterating through fixed list either space macro or permissible characters (letters) list. I hoped there's a command that would simply made all spaces 0pt for instance like `\makebox` with `s`(spread) option that allows to expand spaces, but vice versa.

Comment: You sure? The last one seems not-that-bad to me. (note, node list, not token list)

Comment: @user202729 what do you mean by nodes then? And will it be possible to avoid using Lua?

Comment: About nodes, read `texdoc luatex`. About "avoid using Lua", primitive TeX has a `unhbox` command which might be interesting, take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a list of the commands to remove and to make local definitions for them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\removespaces}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \removespacesdef
  #1%
  \endgroup}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fakehspace}{sm}{}
\newcommand{\fakehskip}{\skip0= }
\newcommand{\fakekern}{\dimen0= }

\newcommand{\removespacesdef}{%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\hspace}{\fakehspace}%
  \let\hskip\fakehskip
  \let\kern\fakekern
  \let~\ignorespaces
  \spaceskip=1sp
}

\begin{document}

\removespaces{Lorem\hspace*{1em}ipsum~dolor\hskip2ex sit\quad
 amet\enspace what \kern0.2em is this?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you get the same without local definitions? No, but as you see you don't need to supply a redefinition for `\quad` or `\enspace`.

Comment: (because `\quad` is implemented in terms of the primitive `\hskip`. As long as they don't switch to use `\@@hskip` or `\tex_hskip:D` instead.)

Comment: @user202729 Of course, the rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Looks neat, especially the way around `\hskip`. Thanks! Why can't `\spaceskip` be zero though?

Comment: @antshar Because if it's zero it's not applied.

Comment: @egreg I can see it, but the question is rather why.

Comment: That should be asked to Knuth.